# Xuggler Transcoder error

Tags: java, ffmpeg, xuggler, transcoding

I tried to follow the instructions from here: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/05/rtmp-to-rtsp-re-stream-using-wowza-and.html

All worked fine, Xuggler has been installed with no errors, all tests passed but now when I try to start the transcoder I get this error:

```
root@heb1:~# java -jar transcoder-1.0.jar
11:25:28.902 [main] WARN  com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibrary - Failure: library load of library: xuggle; url: /tmp/xuggle/xuggle6615346873936202632.tmp; error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/xuggle/xuggle6615346873936202632.tmp: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /tmp/xuggle/xuggle6615346873936202632.tmp)
11:25:46.673 [main] ERROR com.xuggle.xuggler - URL: rtmp://localhost/live/b; Error: could not find output format (../../../../../../../csrc/com/xuggle/xuggler/Container.cpp:513)
java.lang.RuntimeException: could not open output url: rtmp://localhost/live/b
        at com.xuggle.xuggler.Converter.setupStreams(Converter.java:670)
        at com.xuggle.xuggler.Converter.run(Converter.java:1203)
        at com.agilio.transcoder.App.main(App.java:34)
```

So the transcoder sees the input stream, but for the output it says that it can't find the output format, althow it is send to Xuggler:

```
String[] parameters = new String[] { "--acodec", "libfaac", "--vcodec",
                    "libx264", "--vpreset",
                    "/usr/local/xuggler/share/ffmpeg/libx264-ultrafast.ffpreset",
                    inputStream, outputStream };
```

Comment: Something of a shot in the dark, but have you tried appending ".264" to the outputStream URL as in the example?  I don't know exactly how Xuggler does things, but FFmpeg generally needs to know both the video codec and the output format, and unless specified determines the latter from the filename.